# What does DSCP mean for an unmanaged switch?

Tags: networking, switch, qos

While investigating options for better quality-of-service on my LAN I read about [DSCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiated_services) (Differentiated services), which is an updated version of the good old [ToS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_of_service) (Type of Service) in the [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header) header.

I also found that my switches supports DSCP, but I would like to know *how* these packets are treated. Let's take my [Netgear GS105](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/GS105v5) 5 port switch as an example. The [datasheet](https://www.netgear.com/images/datasheet/switches/GS105v5_GS108v4_DS.pdf) has this to say:

> **Traffic Prioritization**
>   […] Support IEEE 802.1p and DSCP-based QoS for delivering data based on priority and type

Great! Just what I need. There is also a table (shortened):

> **Quality of Service (QoS)**
>   DSCP: *Yes*

But what does this actually mean in practice? Is there a published standard for exactly *how* the different classes and bits will cause packets to be prioritized in something that claims to support DSCP?

From having been a simple priority it is now spread over 14 RFCs using expressions like "code points" and "Assured Forwarding behavior group" etc. From reading the article on Wikipedia it is unclear to me how a switch would prioritize between *Telephony*, *Multimedia Conferencing*, and *Real-Time Interactive*.

I understand that this may be up to the individual manufacturer to design, but I'm looking for what an experienced network person would *assume* when seeing the DSCP label on an unmanaged switch.

I also fully understand that as soon as a packet leaves my LAN and goes out to my ISP, all bets are off, but that's not what I care about at this point.

Answer (score 1):

There's a subtle difference between Differentiated Services (DiffServ) and the Differentiated Services Code Point (DSCP). The former is an networking architecture that makes guarantees of QoE while the later is just 6-bits in an IP header.

There are publicized implementations (sort of): [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/quality-of-service-qos/qos-packet-marking/10103-dscpvalues.html) is one of Cisco's implementation. And a [more comprehensive document](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/qos_dfsrv/configuration/15-mt/qos-dfsrv-15-mt-book/qos-dfsrv.html) if you're setting up a corporate sized network.

But these documents above usually apply to whole domains (within a large corporate LAN perhaps). Given your computationally-lacking unmanaged switch, I'd assume that your switch checks those 6 bits, and follows one of the 3 predefined per-hop forwarding behaviors: Default forwarding, expedited forwarding or assured forwarding.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiated_services):

> The problem addressed by DiffServ does not exist in a system that has enough capacity to carry all traffic.

So in other words, your basic switch just has some simple congestion management that really only matters if your down link is saturated and you have some latency sensitive packets that just happen to be using DSCP.